# How to update jslider with an audio file as progress bar

Tags: java, audio, jslider

I have a wav audio file. I know how to play it using AudioImputStream in java. I learned creating a jslider. Now I have to use the slider as a progress bar with the audio, such as the audio plays, so the slider moves forward. And if the user changes the position of slider, the audio file must play from that position.

I'm new to java and there might be some mistakes I might have don in the post. Please overlook them

So i'm stuck at updating the audio track when slider gets updated. I tried adding the changeListner to slider, but I couldn't get it to work.

Here's the code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class audio {

public static void main(String args[])
{

try {
final JFrame f=new JFrame();
File yourFile;
AudioInputStream stream;
AudioFormat format;
DataLine.Info info;
final Clip clip;
yourFile = new File(fileName);

stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(yourFile);
format = stream.getFormat();
final long frames =stream.getFrameLength();
final double durationInSeconds = (frames+0.0) / format.getFrameRate();  
final JSlider slider=new JSlider(0,(int) Math.round(durationInSeconds),0);
info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
clip.open(stream);
clip.start();

f.add(slider);
f.pack();
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
TimerTask timerTask=new TimerTask(){

@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
{
double timeNow=(durationInSeconds*clip.getFramePosition())/frames;
slider.setValue((int)Math.round(timeNow));
f.repaint();
}

}
};
Timer timer = new Timer("MyTimer");//create a new Timer

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 30, 30);//this line starts the timer at the same time its executed


}

catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}


}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried at least something? If so, post your code here so it can be improved. We will not do **all** the work for you.

Comment: I have no idea what you have so far but I'm going to assume you're playing the audio back in a thread using a DataLine, not a Clip. From there its simple math. You start at 0% and the end of the sound file is 100%. Find the length of the audio file then as the audio file plays keep track of how far into the audio file you are and adjust the slider accordingly from the thread. I believe it would be something like currentPositionInTrack / totalLengthOfTrack * 100, hopefully I'm not wrong but that should give you the percentage completed. If you need more help you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: So the problem of updating the slider is solved. I used a timer within which i get the current frame of audio track, convert it to duration and update the timer every 30 milliseconds.

Comment: But i'm still stuck on how to update the track on the slider's updation.

Answer (score 0):

> So the problem of updating the slider is solved. I used a timer within which i get the current frame of audio track, convert it to duration and update the timer every 30 milliseconds.
>
> But i'm still stuck on how to update the track on the slider's updation.

I don't see why you want to update the track manually: if you can already get the current frame of the audio track, it must be updating. So, to solve the problems which you may be facing:

If your slider is not updating properly, I found removing it from the component and then updating it, and then re-adding it to work:

```
@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
{
f.remove(slider);
double timeNow=(durationInSeconds*clip.getFramePosition())/frames;
slider.setValue((int)Math.round(timeNow));
f.add(slider);
f.repaint();
}
```

And if you want to update your clip manually, use `clip.setFramePosition(int frames)`

Answer (score 0):

What I'm observing when I run your code is the following: the JSlider DOES update, but only once per second (or slightly faster).

I don't know if this is the answer, but perhaps it is worth considering. Sometimes calls to repaint are "collapsed". It could be the case that the EDT is not reacting to each repaint call, but instead deciding that adjacent calls are similar enough that they can be collapsed into fewer repaints. I notice, if I put a System.out.println(timeNow) in the TimerTask, about 33 timeNow's are printed on the console per second, which I assume is the rate at which you would prefer your JSlider to update.

I found that if I have a Timer in a separate class (along with its TimerTask) and call a repaint from there, the likelihood that the EDT will collapse repaints is smaller. I recall once before putting a Timer on a JPanel, where having it call "its own" repaint gave me a similar "collapsed EDT" result.

I don't know the exact mechanism or theory behind this. So this might not be the greatest advice. But it still might be worth separating out the timer code into its own class. To do so, you would also have to pass to this class copies of the JFrame and Clip.